# POCO X3 flash fail

Tags: rom-flashing, twrp, xiaomi

TL;DR - Tried to flash TWRP and ended up with TWRP where my OS should be. Have both Mi and TWRP recoveries on device now.

Using a POCO X3(not the pro) and I wanted to install TWRP on it. I found an unofficial build (by a recognized dev) on XDA and proceeded to flash it in fastboot mode. I also pressed the right key combo immediately after running fastboot reboot, but it kept going back to Mi recovery 5.0. I did this a couple more times but to no luck, it'd keep booting to Mi recovery. I then tried booting temporarily into TWRP using fastboot boot command after flashing the boot image one more time. I could access TWRP now, so I thought that's that and powered it off. Then I pressed the recovery combo and Mi recovery flashes on the screen again. I select reboot to system and it then took me to TWRP. So now I have both Mi and TWRP on my device somehow. I don't know what caused this spectacular mess or how to get out of it. Any ideas?

Comment: https://xiaomifirmwareupdater.com/archive/miui/surya

Comment: Note: this applies to Poco X3 NFC. Poco X3 GT does have recovery-ramdisk in boot and requires different install method (flashable zip installer)

Answer (score 0):

download MIUI according to your current version.
in TWRP connect adb shell

```
adb push boot.img /tmp
adb push "TWRP 3.5.0-0 By mahajant99.img" /tmp
adb shell
cd /tmp
dd if=boot.img of=/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/boot
dd if=TWRP\ 3.5.0-0\ By\ mahajant99.img of=/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/recovery
reboot recovery
```

Note: in order to disable avb/dm-verity one must install Magisk. rename Magisk-v24.3.apk -> Magisk-v24.3.zip

```
adb push Magisk-v24.3.zip /tmp
```

TWRP -> Install -> tmp -> Magisk-v24.3.zip -> Swipe to install

Comment: https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk